# Why are my metrics of my CNN not changing with each epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm writing a CNN for MRI image classification. The shape of X is (982, 192, 192, 160), it's a binary classification task. The outcome is not higher or lower than my expectations, but it doesn't seem like the program is learning. I'm fairly new to programming and this is my first time writing a neural network, so I'm lost in where the problem might be. My data is imbalanced. While searching for a solution, I stumbled upon someone with a similar problem and he/she changed the input to a higher value, which I also tried but didn't change anything (first I used 32 in the first layer, 64 in the second, 128 in the third). My code is as follows:

```
Y = labels_df['label_int'].values
X = images

print(len(X), len(Y))

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

print(tf.__version__)

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
print(dummy_y.shape)

from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, dummy_y, test_size=0.2)

print(X_train.shape , X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(192, 192, 160)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.summary()  

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

from keras import backend as K
def recall_m(y_true, y_pred):
        true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
        recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
        return recall

def precision_m(y_true, y_pred):
        true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
        precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
        return precision

def f1_m(y_true, y_pred):
    precision = precision_m(y_true, y_pred)
    recall = recall_m(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))


from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import Metric
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss= 'categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc',f1_m,precision_m, recall_m]) #Change metrics if data is unbalanced!

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, 
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

With the following outcome (the first 10 out of 50 epochs):

```
Train on 785 samples, validate on 197 samples
Epoch 1/50
785/785 [==============================] - 341s 434ms/sample - loss: 1.2855 - acc: 0.6000 - f1_m: 0.6009 - precision_m: 0.6009 - recall_m: 0.6009 - val_loss: 0.6385 - val_acc: 0.6701 - val_f1_m: 0.6616 - val_precision_m: 0.6616 - val_recall_m: 0.6616
Epoch 2/50
785/785 [==============================] - 299s 381ms/sample - loss: 0.6462 - acc: 0.6586 - f1_m: 0.6617 - precision_m: 0.6617 - recall_m: 0.6617 - val_loss: 0.6373 - val_acc: 0.6701 - val_f1_m: 0.6616 - val_precision_m: 0.6616 - val_recall_m: 0.6616
Epoch 3/50
785/785 [==============================] - 294s 374ms/sample - loss: 0.6622 - acc: 0.6586 - f1_m: 0.6529 - precision_m: 0.6529 - recall_m: 0.6529 - val_loss: 0.6348 - val_acc: 0.6701 - val_f1_m: 0.6616 - val_precision_m: 0.6616 - val_recall_m: 0.6616
Epoch 4/50
785/785 [==============================] - 295s 376ms/sample - loss: 0.6430 - acc: 0.6586 - f1_m: 0.6551 - precision_m: 0.6551 - recall_m: 0.6551 - val_loss: 0.6395 - val_acc: 0.6701 - val_f1_m: 0.6616 - val_precision_m: 0.6616 - val_recall_m: 0.6616
Epoch 5/50
785/785 [==============================] - 318s 406ms/sample - loss: 0.6457 - acc: 0.6586 - f1_m: 0.6573 - precision_m: 0.6573 - recall_m: 0.6573 - val_loss: 0.6365 - val_acc: 0.6701 - val_f1_m: 0.6616 - val_precision_m: 0.6616 - val_recall_m: 0.6616
Epoch 6/50
785/785 [==============================] - 296s 376ms/sample - loss: 0.6487 - acc: 0.6586 - f1_m: 0.6584 - precision_m: 0.6584 - recall_m: 0.6584 - val_loss: 0.6352 - val_acc: 0.6701 - val_f1_m: 0.6616 - val_precision_m: 0.6616 - val_recall_m: 0.6616
Epoch 7/50
785/785 [==============================] - 293s 374ms/sample - loss: 0.6467 - acc: 0.6586 - f1_m: 0.6606 - precision_m: 0.6606 - recall_m: 0.6606 - val_loss: 0.6447 - val_acc: 0.6701 - val_f1_m: 0.6616 - val_precision_m: 0.6616 - val_recall_m: 0.6616
Epoch 8/50
785/785 [==============================] - 294s 374ms/sample - loss: 0.6480 - acc: 0.6586 - f1_m: 0.6606 - precision_m: 0.6606 - recall_m: 0.6606 - val_loss: 0.6552 - val_acc: 0.6701 - val_f1_m: 0.6616 - val_precision_m: 0.6616 - val_recall_m: 0.6616
Epoch 9/50
785/785 [==============================] - 297s 378ms/sample - loss: 0.6452 - acc: 0.6586 - f1_m: 0.6628 - precision_m: 0.6628 - recall_m: 0.6628 - val_loss: 0.6344 - val_acc: 0.6701 - val_f1_m: 0.6616 - val_precision_m: 0.6616 - val_recall_m: 0.6616
Epoch 10/50
785/785 [==============================] - 294s 374ms/sample - loss: 0.6461 - acc: 0.6586 - f1_m: 0.6595 - precision_m: 0.6595 - recall_m: 0.6595 - val_loss: 0.6378 - val_acc: 0.6701 - val_f1_m: 0.6616 - val_precision_m: 0.6616 - val_recall_m: 0.6616
```

The loss keeps dropping, but the accuracy remains the same until the 50th epoch as well as val_f1, val_precision and val_recall. Also my validation accuracy is higher than my train accuracy and I don't understand why. Am I overlooking something, or missing some steps?

Comment: As for the "validation accuracy" being higher than the "test accuracy" even though you use the same samples for both, I could not find the section of the code where you compute the "test accuracy". Could you please provide this?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the validation accuracy is higher than the **train** accuracy. I edited this in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first epoch to the second, the loss drops by half and the accuracy increases by about five percent. However, after the second epoch the loss does not seem to decrease significantly to affect the accuracy. This is because of the fact that the softmax activation in the last layer outputs a "probability" distribution over the classes and the categorical crossentropy loss would improve if this distribution moves towards the true distribution. This does not necessarily affect the crisp class label prediction and ergo not the accuracy and f1 scores. As for the validation accuracy being slightly higher than the training accuracy, it could very well happen.